# Find integers solutions for which bivariate polynomial with bi-quadratic form: $4x^2y^2-4xy^2+1$, becomes a square number

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, integers, square-numbers

Could you help me to find all integer $x$ and $y$ for which the bivariate polynomial:

$$4x^2y^2-4xy^2+1$$

is a square number, i.e., it can be expressed as $z^2$ for some integer $z$? From the above, one can see that $z$ is an odd number.

I heuristically found a solution $x=2,y=6$ for which it becomes $17^2$. However, I am seeking a systemic way to find all the solutions, or a specialized way that can solve my specific problem.

Note that **the above polynomial is bi-quadratic**, that is, by fixing each variable, it becomes a univariate quadratic in the other one.

Comment: Trivially $x\in \{0, 1\}, y\in \mathbb Z$ works, so does $y\in \{0, \pm1\}, x\in \mathbb Z$.  Presumably you want other solutions.  Where did you come across this problem?

Comment: Pretty cute.  What is the source of the problem???

Comment: Thanks for your comments!
I see your concern; no contest no exam. If the above problem is solved, I can determine all sqaure numbers with an interesting pattern. It is for fun, as my research area is operations research and management science. @WillJagy: It should be very interesting that you have a complete solution. In an email, I sent you the pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is closed form if you know how to deal with the traditional Pell equation; a useful topic that is part of that story is (simple) continued fractions. With your letters, restrict $x \geq 2.$   Then give names
$$W = (2x-1)^2 - 1 \; , \; \; \; k = 4x - 2$$
you are asking for positive $y$   in
$$  z^2 -  W  y^2 = 1 $$
Worth learning how this works;  the $y$ values are
$$ y: \; \; 0,  1,  k,  k^2 - 1, k^3 -2k, .... $$
which gives a simple linear recurrence when we index the $y's,$
$$  y_{j+2} = k y_{j+1}  - y_j $$
The $z$ values have the same recurrence $  z_{j+2} = k z_{j+1}  - z_j $ However, the starting values are a little different, so we get
$$  z: \; \;  1,  \frac{k}{2},  \frac{k^2}{2} - 1,   \frac{k^3}{2} - 1, .... $$

The relation between  the $y$ values and the $z$  values  is analogous to that between the Fibonacci and Lucas numbers.

You can also write a Binet type formula  by introducing a quantity $\lambda$ that satisfies $\lambda^2 - k \lambda + 1 = 0,$ or
$$ \lambda = \frac{k + \sqrt{k^2-4}}{2}   $$

Oh, I thought negative $x$  would need work, but $x$   and $1-x$   get the same sequence of $y$ values.

I did a raw search,   your $2 \leq x \leq 5$  and $y \geq 0$  up to fairly large.

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

```
Sat 13 Jan 2024 09:20:21 AM PST

  x: 2  y: 0  z:  1  
  x: 2  y: 1  z:  3  
  x: 2  y: 6  z:  17  
  x: 2  y: 35  z:  99  
  x: 2  y: 204  z:  577  
  x: 2  y: 1189  z:  3363  
  x: 2  y: 6930  z:  19601  
  x: 2  y: 40391  z:  114243  
  x: 2  y: 235416  z:  665857  

  x: 3  y: 0  z:  1  
  x: 3  y: 1  z:  5  
  x: 3  y: 10  z:  49  
  x: 3  y: 99  z:  485  
  x: 3  y: 980  z:  4801  
  x: 3  y: 9701  z:  47525  
  x: 3  y: 96030  z:  470449  
  x: 3  y: 950599  z:  4656965  

  x: 4  y: 0  z:  1  
  x: 4  y: 1  z:  7  
  x: 4  y: 14  z:  97  
  x: 4  y: 195  z:  1351  
  x: 4  y: 2716  z:  18817  
  x: 4  y: 37829  z:  262087  
  x: 4  y: 526890  z:  3650401  
  x: 4  y: 7338631  z:  50843527  

  x: 5  y: 0  z:  1  
  x: 5  y: 1  z:  9  
  x: 5  y: 18  z:  161  
  x: 5  y: 323  z:  2889  
  x: 5  y: 5796  z:  51841  
  x: 5  y: 104005  z:  930249  
  x: 5  y: 1866294  z:  16692641  
  x: 5  y: 33489287  z:  299537289
```

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

Comment: Thank you! I cannot see how solutions $(y_j,z_j)$ satisfy the Pell equation. Are the sequences are $0, 1, k, k^2 ...$ and $1, k, k^2...$ (given the recurrences of both $y, z$ are the same)?

Comment: I think, given the above sequence for $y$, the $z$ sequence is $1,\frac{k}{2}, \frac{k^2}{2}-1,...$

Comment: Right. It all comes down to Cayley-Hamilton for the "automorphism" matrix $$ \left( 
\begin{array}{rr} 
2x-1 & W \\ 
1 & 2x-1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$   which sends a correct (vertical) $(z,y)$ vector to the next correct one.

Comment: Thank you Will for the update! A few questions: 1) Have you generated the numbers using the  system $\left (z_{j+1}, y_{j+1} \right)^t=A \left (z_{j}, y_{j} \right)^t$, with the automorphism matrix $A$ given above or the two proposed recurrences? 2) I think the recurrence $  z_{j+2} = k z_{j+1}  - z_j $ given in the answer needs to be changed; Could you let me know the correct one? 3) Did you derive the recurrence $  y_{j+2} = k y_{j+1}  - y_j $ based on the  system $\left (z_{j+1}, y_{j+1} \right)^t=A \left (z_{j}, y_{j} \right)^t$ or derive it heuristically?

Comment: You stated " ...  $y_{j+2} = k y_{j+1}  - y_j.$  The $z$ values have the same recurrence $  z_{j+2} = k z_{j+1}  - z_j $ ..."

Based on this, y and z sequences become: $0, 1, k, k^2,...$ and $1, k, k^2,...$. For $k=6$, the z sequence is $1, 6, 36, ...$ not $1, 3, 17, ...$.

Comment: In my output above, I named the letters $x,y,z$   The $y$ values are $1, k, k^2 - 1$   while the $z$  values start $1, \frac{k}{2}$

Comment: Please check the recurrence of z, you provided in the answer. It does not generate $1, k/2, k^2/2-1, ...$

Comment: @Amir, please print out my little table of output above  and make marks on it while going through the whole business with actaul numbers.As I had said, this comes from Cayley-Hamilton   for the matrix above.  The trace of it is $k=4x-2$  while the determinant is one.  Off to the drugstore

Comment: Thanks for the update. A very nice and complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

$$4x^2y^2-4xy^2=a^2-1$$
$$4y^2 \cdot(x^2-x) = a^2-1$$

As $a$ is prime, you can mostly write it as $a=2b+1$, or:

$$4y^2 \cdot(x^2-x) = 4b^2+4b$$

Or:
$$y^2 \cdot [x \cdot (x-1)] = b \cdot (b+1)$$

So, set $y=1$ and $x=b+1$ and should get something.

E.g. for $a=17$:$ b=8$, set $y=1$ and $x=9$.

(This is not the general answer, but it gives a good idea.)

Comment: Why is $a$ prime?

Comment: Thank you! You may replace "prime" with "odd" above.  I already checked some simple cases in which, $x=1, 2$ or $y=1, 2$, but I don't know how the general case can be handled to find all solutions.